# jQuery selector by position on page available?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a selector available in jQuery to select elements which have a specific position of the page, for example all elements that have an offsetTop bigger than, say, 100px?

I tried:

```
$('span[offsetTop>100]')
```

because just as we can check if an attribute equals to some value, I thought it might be possible to check if an attribute is larger than some value. This, however, does not work. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd need to use the [`filter()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter `<span>` elements by their offset:

```
$('span').filter(function() {
    return $(this).offset().top > 100;
});
```